# Ignore specific words in path string

Tags: python, regex

I have to process long paths and I'd like to ignore specific words:

```
'/home/me/data/dataset/images/dark-side_23---83971436re.jpg'
'/home/me/data/dataset/images/medium-side_23---83971436re.jpg'
'/home/me/data/dataset/images/others_23---83971436re.jpg'
```

So the output should be:

```
side
side
others
```

I'm using this regex:

```
pat = re.compile(r'/([^/]+)_\d+---.*.jpg$')
re.search(pat, path_string).groups()
```

And I've tried something with negative lookup but doesn't work:

```
pat = re.compile(r'/(?!dark|medium)([^/]+)_\d+---.*.jpg$')
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention that they could exist another strings like:

```
'/home/me/data/dataset/images/light-side_23---83971436re.jpg'
```

Where it should return:

```
light-side
```

So using the "-" character won't be useful in this case.

Comment: Try `([^-/]+)_\d+---.*\.jpg$` or `([^-/]+)_\d+---[^/]*\.jpg$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6RS26e/1)

Comment: So you want `side` out of `'/home/me/data/dataset/images/medium-side_23---83971436re.jpg'` where as `light-side` out of `'/home/me/data/dataset/images/light-side_23---83971436re.jpg'` Hmm

Comment: Try `(?:(?:dark|medium)-)?([^/]+)_\d+---[^/]*\.jpg$`, see https://regex101.com/r/6RS26e/3

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew that's the correct one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:(?:dark|medium)-)?([^/]+)_\d+---[^/]*\.jpg$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6RS26e/3/)

**Details**

- `(?:(?:dark|medium)-)?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 repetitions of

  - `(?:dark|medium)`  - `dark` or `medium` words (if you want to only avoid matching them as whole words use `(?:\b(?:dark|medium)-)?`)
  - `-` - a hyphen
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `/`
- `_` - an underscore
- `\d+` -  1+ digits
- `---` - three hyphens
- `[^/]*` - 0+ chars other than `/`
- `\.jpg` - `.jpg` substring (`.` is special, thus, must be escaped)
- `$` - end of string.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/PHaJVE):

```
import re
strs = ['/home/me/data/dataset/images/dark-side_23----83971436re.jpg',
            '/home/me/data/dataset/images/medium-side_23---83971436re.jpg',
            '/home/me/data/dataset/images/others_23---83971436re.jpg',
            '/home/me/data/dataset/images/light-side_23---83971436re.jpg']
rx = re.compile(r'(?:(?:dark|medium)-)?([^/]+)_\d+---[^/]*\.jpg$')
for s in strs:
    m = rx.search(s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
side
side
others
light-side
```

**NOTE** that you may simplify it a bit if you first grab the last subpart by using `os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(s))`. Then, you may use `r'^(?:(?:dark|medium)-)?(.+)_\d+---.*\.jpg$'`. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/yJvnOL).

Answer (score 1):

Using `([^/]+)_\d+---.*\.jpg$` with a condition:

```
import re
str_list = ['/home/me/data/dataset/images/dark-side_23----83971436re.jpg',
            '/home/me/data/dataset/images/medium-side_23---83971436re.jpg',
            '/home/me/data/dataset/images/others_23---83971436re.jpg',
            '/home/me/data/dataset/images/light-side_23---83971436re.jpg']

pat = re.compile(r'([^/]+)_\d+---.*\.jpg$')
for s in str_list:
    if "light" in s:
        print(re.search(pat, s).group(1))
    else:
        print(re.search(pat, s).group(1).rpartition('-')[2])
```

OUTPUT:

```
side
side
others
light-side
```

Comment: This might capture the word in a wrong part of the path. OP did not specify that though, if it can only appear in the last subpart or not.

Comment: Note that `[^//]` = `[^/]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, fixed.